# Helm doesn't configure what I mean

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ce, helm3

My command is to install a GitLab chart on my microK8s cluster. In this command, I want to instruct Helm to deploy a GitLab-CE with some configuration on volume size.

```
$ microk8s.helm3 install gitlab-ce gitlab/gitlab --set global.hosts.domain=demo.jesaya,global.hosts.externalIP=10.8.60.205,global.edition=ce \
--set certmanager-issuer.email=example@gmail.com \
--set minio.persistence.size=5Gi \
--set prometheus.server.persistentVolume.size=2Gi \
--set redis.master.persistence.size=2Gi \
--set gitlab-runner.install=false \
--set gitlab.gitaly.persistence.size=5Gi \
--set postgresql.primary.master.persistence.size=2Gi,postgresql.primary.livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds=600,postgresql.primary.readinessProbe.initialDelaySeconds=630 \
-n gitlab-ce
```

My PVC summary:

```
$ microk8s.kubectl get pvc
NAME                                  STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
gitlab-ce-minio                       Bound    pvc-81b221d4-7294-4cd5-b771-f21a7c03741c   5Gi        RWO            nfs0           12m
gitlab-ce-prometheus-server           Bound    pvc-ba159b8b-30f4-42b4-b27a-fdbe66eb678a   2Gi        RWO            nfs0           12m
redis-data-gitlab-ce-redis-master-0   Bound    pvc-6d1ed8ea-f502-4db9-84e7-40e3a083bbda   2Gi        RWO            nfs0           11m
repo-data-gitlab-ce-gitaly-0          Bound    pvc-f1da1672-5aa6-4563-a988-db38cdc38991   5Gi        RWO            nfs0           11m
data-gitlab-ce-postgresql-0           Bound    pvc-54095a82-ca79-4d75-badc-39778dc3bc90   8Gi        RWO            nfs0           11m
```

The GitLab Chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: 14.9.3
dependencies:
- name: gitlab
  repository: ""
  version: '*.*.*'
- name: certmanager-issuer
  repository: ""
  version: '*.*.*'
- name: minio
  repository: ""
  version: '*.*.*'
- name: registry
  repository: ""
  version: '*.*.*'
- alias: certmanager
  condition: certmanager.install
  name: cert-manager
  repository: https://charts.jetstack.io/
  version: 1.5.4
- condition: prometheus.install
  name: prometheus
  repository: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
  version: 15.0.4
- condition: postgresql.install
  name: postgresql
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
  version: 8.9.4
- condition: gitlab-runner.install
  name: gitlab-runner
  repository: https://charts.gitlab.io/
  version: 0.39.0
- condition: global.grafana.enabled
  name: grafana
  repository: https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
  version: 6.9.1
- condition: redis.install
  name: redis
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
  version: 11.3.4
- condition: nginx-ingress.enabled
  name: nginx-ingress
  repository: ""
  version: '*.*.*'
description: Web-based Git-repository manager with wiki and issue-tracking features.
home: https://about.gitlab.com/
icon: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gitlab-artwork/raw/master/logo/logo-square.png
keywords:
- gitlab
maintainers:
- email: support@gitlab.com
  name: GitLab Inc.
name: gitlab
sources:
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab
version: 5.9.3
```

I didn't find any root cause here. Another PostgreSQL chart configuration like readiness and liveness also does not work properly like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

I should have referenced this file because it was using an old version.
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/09ba1564fed3df4f1d94518edcb58aab1f75c827/bitnami/postgresql/values.yaml